# How to use zip to easily get the dataframe for each of the coin pair in the list through a defined function? (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

**I have defined a function which can get the history price for the coin:**

```py
def get_price(pair):
    df=binance.fetch_ohlcv(pair,limit=258,timeframe="1d")
    df=pd.DataFrame(df).rename(columns={0:"date",1:"open",2:"high",3:"low",4:"close",5:"volume"})
    df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"],unit="ms")+pd.Timedelta(hours=8)
    df.set_index("date",inplace=True)
    return df
```

Then i  want to use zip function to create two lists which can correspond to each other,so i can easily apply the function to get history data for each of the coin in the name list:

```py
name=["btc","eth"]
symbol=["BTC/USDT","ETH/USDT"] 
for name,pair in zip(name,symbol):
    name=get_price(pair)
eth
```

But when i type "eth",to get the dataframe of "ETH/USDT", it gave me the error of "NameError: name 'eth' is not defined". The reason for me to do this is if i have a list of more than 10 pairs of coins, i dont want to use get_price function for each of them one by one in order to get the history data for all of them. can anyone help me to fix this errors? Thanks[image]

Comment: why are you typing `eth`? Your function is runs inside the `for` loop. Just typing `eth` does not makes sense.

Comment: For reference if you were trying to create an arbitrary number of variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to do another function if you want to keep the things the way you have.
The first part (where you get the df seems fine since you have checked it). The issue is with the second part, where you are trying to run that function. Change is as below may help.

**Example** Run this & it will print `ETH/USDT` as output.

```
def func(x):
    name=["btc","eth"]
    symbol=["BTC/USDT","ETH/USDT"] 
    for name,pair in zip(name,symbol):
        if name == x:
            print(pair)
func('eth')
```

Similarly, if you want to run the function of getting the df, try something like this.

```
def func(x):
    name=["btc","eth"]
    symbol=["BTC/USDT","ETH/USDT"] 
    for name,pair in zip(name,symbol):
        if name == x:
            get_price(pair)
func('eth')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use a `dict` to store the `dataframes`

### Original Code:

```py
name=["btc","eth"]
symbol=["BTC/USDT","ETH/USDT"] 
for name,pair in zip(name,symbol):
    name=get_price(pair)
```

- The loop is trying to assign a `pd.DataFrame` object, to a string, which won't work.

  - I'm surprised that didn't cause a `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`
  - Equivalently, `name=get_price(pair)` → `'eth' = pd.DataFrame()`
- From the notebook, I see can a list of names and symbols, for which you're trying to create individual dataframes.
- The notebook shows, `get_price` returns a dataframe, when given a symbol.

### Replacement Code:

- The following code will create a `dict` of dataframes, where each `string` in `name`, is a `key`.

```py
df_dict = dict()
for name, pair in zip(name, symbol):
    df_dict[name] = get_price(pair)

df_dict['eth']
```